# are or have the same price and different designs?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality-in-context

I am going to make up two sentences below.

> 1. All the different computers in this section **are or have** the same price.
> 2. These watches **have or are** different designs.

I have heard people use either choice when I shop in stores.

Which one is actually correct - are or have?

Comment: Can you tell us which verb you believe is correct, and why? If you have done any research on your own, please use the [edit] link to add it to your question. This helps us to provide a useful answer!

Comment: @P.E.Dant Are you from UK or US. I always notice that you add "**to**" after the verb **help**. I never do it.

Comment: @SovereignSun I think can you use either bare infinitive or to-infinitive; both are correct.

Comment: _Help_ is used with or without the preposition. I don't believe it's idiomatic to omit or include it in any vernacular.

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions are possible in the first sentence. Both of them mean the same thing.

- All the different computers in this section **are/have** the same price.

However, with the second sentence it is grammatically correct to add the preposition "**of**" after **are**:

- These watches **are of/have** different designs.

It just happens that the word you picked for this example, "designs", has multiple meanings.  "Design" can refer to either the scheme for how the components of the watch will work, or a decorative pattern applied to the watch.  So if it is used with **have**, the meaning of the sentence would depend on the context. If **are of** is used, it could have only the first meaning.

Comment: The "of" might be technically correct, but almost never used in speech in this context (at least in AmE).  That said, "are of different designs" probably wouldn't sound strange if someone said it.  "Are of the same price" actually sounds off; I'd have to think about why.  Maybe it's because in this context, "of" is associated with being part of something larger or a set, and "the same price" doesn't fit.  But even "are of different prices" doesn't sound natural.  Not sure why

Comment: @fixer1234 I'd like your answer then with a full research, since that's what I learned from books. However, I can see what you mean. The "**of**" may indeed be overused in the first example.

Comment: Maybe one of the English majors can explain why "price" is different from design. I can't see a rule that would make it different, but for some reason, it sounds off to my native ear.  In the second sentence, the "of" might be included in formal or technical writing, but it wouldn't typically be included in everyday speech.  It's probably just the routine dropping of words unnecessary to the meaning.

Comment: @fixer1234 Without "**of**" it reads like, **these watches aren't watches - they are different designs (of watches maybe)**

Comment: It relies on context.  If you said "These watches are zebras", that would clearly mean they weren't watches.  "Design" is a property of watches (and other man-made things), so there's no reason to assume it doesn't refer to a property of the watch.  "These watches are different designs" is assumed to mean "These watches are **of** different designs."  "These watches **have** different designs" could be used in speech to refer to either the same meaning as "are of"), or to artistic patterns on the watches.  It would be ambiguous without some other context.

Comment: @fixer1234 +1 That's a good point. I think I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeh, you are right, I can feel this difference but it's rather hard to explain it in a simple and understandable way. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234 and SovereignSun for your detailed explanations.

Comment: @SovereignSun, that "of" issue I mentioned in the 1st comment bugged me, so I posted a [question about it on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395510/natural-vs-unnatural-use-of-of).  I think EditingFrank might have hit on the answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 You might be on to something. I like both answers; they both have some truth. I mean, maybe indeed the **of** is outdated.